# Make error show conditional message?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How would I get my error message to be conditional like this:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>

  <% if object.errors.count = 1 %>
    Oops, an error was found.
  <% else %>
    Oops, <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "errors") %> were found
  <% end %>

  <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
    <%= msg %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

I get a `undefined method count=` error right now. What would be the correct way?

Comment: Don't you wanna compare if object.errors.count == 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where you have

```
 <% if object.errors.count = 1 %>
```

you need to have:

```
 <% if object.errors.count == 1 %>
```

note the double equal sign.